# How to log slow queries in MySQL 5.0.45

Tags: mysql, logging

I am trying to turn on logging of slow queries on MySQL v5.0.45 (compile OS: redhat-linus-gnu), but I can't seem to get it working.  I tried adding...

```
long_query_time = 1
```

to my /etc/my.cnf file as the last option under the [mysqld] section and then I restarted using the command...

```
sudo /sbin/service mysqld restart --log-slow-queries=/var/log/slowqueries.log
```

Then I ran programs where I know the SELECT query is taking around 6-8 seconds, but I can't find the log anywhere.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

For MySQL 5.0, the variable you want to use in my.cnf is:

```
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mylogname.log
```

You will need to create this file manually and set ownership and group to mysql. You can do this on the command line with:

```
touch /var/log/mylogname.log
chown mysql /var/log/mylogname.log
chgrp mysql /var/log/mylogname.log
```

You can also set the length of time that you consider "long" with:

```
long_query_time = 2
```

You can add queries that are performed without indexes using:

```
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

But, this might fill up your log really fast.

I found it strange that some variables use underscores and some use hyphens, and it can be different depending on how you set the variables, through my.cnf, or through the command line. Here is a list of all system variables you can set in MySQL 5.0: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html

Something else weird is: this documentation says that log-slow-queries is a Boolean value, and when I check my global variables (in mysql, type 'show global variables;'), it shows the value of this as 'ON', not as the file path I set it to. Regardless, this worked for me, and it wrote the file.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. It not only covers how to setup and configure slow queries in mysql 5.0.XX perfectly, but it also points out all the weird quirks surrounding it that I've noticed over the years, but never seen listed out so concisely.

Answer (score 0):

In your /etc/my.cnf add `log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/slowqueries.log` and then restart mysql as usual, e.g. `sudo service mysqld restart` and give that a try.

Comment: Hmm... no luck.  I still can't get the queries to be logged.

Comment: sudo service mysqld restart
service: This command still works, but it is deprecated. Please use launchctl(8) instead.
service: unrecognized command 'restart'